# Java: INSERT INTO inside a loop using Result Test

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, resultset

I am having a small problem while I try to insert some data in my database (MS - SQL). 
I am using this code (I just copy-paste all of it, so someone might understand smth that I don't)

```
 try 
              {
                  Connection connection = null;
                  Statement Statement = null;
                  ResultSet ResultSet = null;
                  String query = "";

              // jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
              String host = "jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=db";
              String username = "user";
              String password = "pass";
              Statement = connection.createStatement();
              DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
              Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

              DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
              Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

              for (int k = 0; k < idArray.length ; k ++ )
              {
                  query = "INSERT INTO Companies (ID,Company,Company2,Company3,Country,ZIP,City,Street," +
                        "Phone,Fax,Email,Internet,CustomerNo,AccountMngr,Icon,AddressSource," +
                        "UserDefined1,UserDefined2,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,ColectedInformation) " +
                        " VALUES ('" + UUID.randomUUID() + "','" + company_nameArray[k] 
                                + "','" + company_name2Array[k] + "','" + company_name3Array[k] + "','DE','"   
                                + zipArray[k] + "','" + cityArray[k] + "','" + streetArray[k] + "','"  
                                + phone_Array[k] + "','" + faxArray[k] + "','" + emailArray[k] + "','"
                                + internetArray[k] + "','" + customer_noArray[k] 
                                + "','d','131','60','Baufinder Import','Import Datum "
                                + dateFormat1.format(cal1.getTime()) + "','" 
                                + dateFormat1.format(cal1.getTime()) + "','d','" 
                                + "cxcxvcx" +  
                                "')";

                  ResultSet = Statement.executeQuery(query);   
              }

              connection.close();
          }
          catch(NullPointerException e)
          {
                System.out.println("NullPointerException");
          }
          catch ( SQLException err ) 
          {
              System.out.println( "SQL Exception:" ) ;

              // Loop through the SQL Exceptions
              while( err != null )
                 {
                  System.out.println( "State  : " + err.getSQLState()  ) ;
                  System.out.println( "Message: " + err.getMessage()   ) ;
                  System.out.println( "Error  : " + err.getErrorCode() ) ;

                  err = err.getNextException() ;
                 }
          }
          catch( Exception e )
          {
              System.out.println( "There is a problem with " + e ) ;
          }

    }
```

and I am getting this error:

> SQL Exception: State  : null 
>   Message: There was no result set returned by the statement.
>   Error  : 0

I don't understand the problem with the result test. I have been using it a lot, since I try to read the data from another database and now I try to insert them to another. 
Furthermore, all of these tables do not include null values.

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: **executeUpdate** instead of `executeQuery`. Returns the number of changes (int).

Comment: This is incredibly confusing: `ResultSet ResultSet = null` use naming conventions and ensure variable names begin with lowercase. E.g. `Resultset resultSet = null`

Comment: @JoopEggen I don't really get what you mean. I cannot do resultset = Statement.executeUpdate(query);

Comment: simply leave out `resultset = ` ;)

Comment: ... and please note that any time you use 'outside' data, you need to use [parameterized queries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), or you risk SQL Injection.

Comment: @DimitraMicha thanks for your acceptance proposal, but comment is fine. The error was a minor oversight only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Statement#executeUpdate(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) instead of Statement#execute(query);

```
for (int k = 0; k < idArray.length ; k ++ )
          {
              query = "INSERT INTO Companies (ID,Company,Company2,Company3,Country,ZIP,City,Street," +
                    "Phone,Fax,Email,Internet,CustomerNo,AccountMngr,Icon,AddressSource," +
                    "UserDefined1,UserDefined2,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,ColectedInformation) " +
                    " VALUES ('" + UUID.randomUUID() + "','" + company_nameArray[k] 
                            + "','" + company_name2Array[k] + "','" + company_name3Array[k] + "','DE','"   
                            + zipArray[k] + "','" + cityArray[k] + "','" + streetArray[k] + "','"  
                            + phone_Array[k] + "','" + faxArray[k] + "','" + emailArray[k] + "','"
                            + internetArray[k] + "','" + customer_noArray[k] 
                            + "','d','131','60','Baufinder Import','Import Datum "
                            + dateFormat1.format(cal1.getTime()) + "','" 
                            + dateFormat1.format(cal1.getTime()) + "','d','" 
                            + "cxcxvcx" +  
                            "')";

              int updatedRowCount = Statement.executeUpdate(query);   
          }
```

Notes:

1. Please consider using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to prevent possibility of *SQL Injection* if some data directly input by User.
2. Try to use [batch insert](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/) if you need to improve performance of inserting.

Comment: Thanks Taky! I should have just removed ResultTest and use executeUpdate in the same time:)