# Java: Insert into a table datetime data

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, datetime, jdbc

I am trying to insert into a variable in MS- SQL database the current date and the time.
I use this format:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

and I get this as a result 2013-01-28 09:29:37.941

My field in the database is defined `datetime` and as I have seen in other tables which have the same field, the date and the time is written exactly like this 2011-07-05 14:18:33.000.

I try to insert into the database with a query that I do inside a java program, but I get this error

> SQL Exception: State  : S0003 Message: The conversion of a varchar
>   data type to a datetime data type of the value is out of range. Error 
>   : 242

My query is like that:

```
query = "INSERT INTO Companies CreatedOn"+ 
         "VALUES ('" + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) + "')"
```

but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: print the query content, and then try to run that in mssql directly (for example using sql server management studio).

Comment: value of "cal" is most probably too large for sql server to handle it.

Comment: You should use a preparedstatement http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29.

Comment: Don't format it, check out this constructor http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp%28long%29

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [error description](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-242.aspx), you are inserting an incorrect type into the database. See [JDBC to MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878.aspx). You should convert Calendar to [Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

Try using:

```
PrepareStatement statement 
    = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Companies CreatedOn VALUES(?)");
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
statement.setTimestamp(1, timstamp);
int insertedRecordsCount = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I am trying to do that, but then some other problems come up. "There was no result set returned by the statement.", which I think is because I am doing smth really wrong in my program.

Comment: You do not recieve ResultSet after insert records. You may only monitor updated rows count.

Comment: How do you execute statement? Show please exception stack trace.

Comment: Basically, it is the other problem that I have posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525690/java-insert-into-inside-a-loop-using-result-test

Answer (score 3):

First of all, do NOT use string concatenation. Have you ever heart about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Correct way how to do that is to use prepared statement:

Idea is you define statement with placeholders and than you define value for those placeholders.

See [@Taky'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558289/java-insert-into-a-table-datetime-data#14558378)s answer for more details.

Comment: need to setTimestamp() because column has Datetime type.

Comment: I am reading now about SQL injection. I hadn't realised that it may cause so many problems when I use string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

`dateFormat#format` this method returns formatted string not `Date` object. Database field is `DateTime` and it is expecting `java.sql.Timestamp` to be inserted there not `String` according to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

Try `java.sql.Timestamp` object instead of String in query and I'd recommend you to use `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to save String date value to Date type DB field.

convert it to Data dataType

You can also use the [datetime](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp) "unseparated" format `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Nope, the error message states that the problem is elsewhere - I posted the same response and then deleted it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) framework to work with date/time.
It maps own date/time types to Hibernate/SQL types without problem.
When you set parameters in HQL query joda carries about right type mapping.

Comment: but he is not using hibernate, but JDBC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store current date and time then you should use **MYSQL** inbuilt method **NOW()**.
for brief documentation refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html . so your code will be like.

```
INSERT INTO Companies CreatedOn VALUES(NOW())"
```

However If you want to do it using java Date-util then it should be

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```