# This code of inserting data to database throwing exception. Help me regarding this code. I am new to StackOverflow

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

```
<%
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
       
       

           String o=request.getParameter("Order_ID");
           String c=request.getParameter("Customer_Name");
           String c2=request.getParameter("Customer_ID");
           String o2=request.getParameter("Order_Amount");
           String n=request.getParameter("Notes");
           String o3=request.getParameter("Order_Date");

 String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/winter_internship";

 PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
     // Load JBBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
      int updateQuery = 0;
 
     
 if(o!=null && c!=null && c2!=null && o2!=null && n!=null && o3!=null){
         // check if the text box having only blank spaces
     if(o!="" && c!="" && c2!="" && o2!="" && n!="" && o3!="") {
                 try {
          
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "misspooh2068");
                        // sql query to insert values in the secified table.
          String queryString = "insert into order_details(Order_ID,Customer_Name,Customer_ID,Order_Amount,Notes,Order_Date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                  
          pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
                  pstatement.setString(1, o);
                  pstatement.setString(2, c);
                  pstatement.setString(3, c2);
                  pstatement.setString(4, o2);
                  pstatement.setString(7, n);
                  pstatement.setString(8, o3);
          updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
                        if (updateQuery != 0) { %>
           <br>
           <TABLE style="background-color: #E3E4FA;" 
               WIDTH="30%" border="1">
          <tr><th>Data is inserted successfully 
                in database.</th></tr>
       </table>
          <%
          }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        out.println("Unable to connect to database.");

           }
        finally {
            // close all the connections.
            pstatement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
  }
}
%>
```

[MY Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G14KN.png)

When I ran this code it throws exception and returns unable to connect to database

[Image regarding exception throw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jKhQ.png)

Tried to find many solutions but exception is kept on throwing. I am new to StackOverflow.

Cheers Guys! Help me out guys :)

Comment: See your server logs if there any errors . Also try printing `ex.printStackTrace();` .

Comment: Parameter index out of range (7 > number of parameters, which is 6). @Swati

Comment: there is typo in your code  `pstatement.setString(7..` it should be `5` and next `6` .

Comment: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'a' for column 'Order_Date' at row 1

How to add date and time in sql database using jsp.. 

Format : 2020-09-01 00:00:00

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558289/java-insert-into-a-table-datetime-data) might help

Comment: not working date and time issue

Comment: Currently your date is in string format you need to convert it into required format . There are many example for that have a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+string+to+datetime+in+sql+java&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN857IN857&oq=convert+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39l2j0i457j69i60j69i65j69i61j69i60.8647j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) .